# Compress string with repeated groups

Tags: regex

I have a string `"aa > aa > bbb > ccc > ccc > ccc > dd > aa"` is there an elegant way of compressing it to  `"aa > bbb > ccc > dd > aa"` using regexp alone (rather than parsing to a vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a string in the format `word > word > word ...` and a regex engine that supports backreferences you can use

```
\b(\w+)(?: > \1\b)+
```

And replace it with

```
$1
```

(or however your engine of choice notes a backreference to the first capturing group)

This uses a backreference and word boundaries to ensure that exactly the same word has been matched again.

Some sample cases are here: https://regex101.com/r/UOnKeM/1